# How should I visually represent these preference rankings?

Tags: data-visualization, ranking, ranks

I'm trying to visually represent the following rankings in a clear and intuitive way, but am unsure of how to best do that. Here's the data:

There are 4 outcomes: A1, A2, B1, B2
The letters are the main outcomes and the numbers are variants of the outcomes.

John ranks these outcomes (from best to worst) in the following order: A1, B1, B2, A2
Mary ranks these outcomes (from best to worst) in the following order: B1, A1, B2, A2

The result I want to emphasize (visually) is that the variants of A are ranked as both the best outcomes (in John's ranking) and the worst outcomes in all rankings.

I'd also like to be able to represent the size of difference between outcomes. For example, how might I represent that the difference between A2 and B2 is larger than the difference between B2 and B1?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!